# Обновление и отображение данных таблицы в Delphi компонент TIBQuery и TIBTable

Tags: firebird, delphi-xe2, база-данных

В Delphi я сделал добавление записи в таблицу через TIBTable, а в TIBQuery находится sql `SELECT * FROM autors`. Этот TIBQuery присоединён к таблице отображения TDBGrid. Так вот, новая запись (введённая через TIBTable) в БД попадает, но не отображается сразу же в TDBGrid. Вот код, который у меня написан:

```
//FM_Data.IBTransaction1.StartTransaction;
FM_Data.IBT_Autors.Insert;
FM_Data.IBT_Autors.FieldByName('NAME').AsString := FM_AddAutor.E_AddedAutorName.Text;
FM_Data.IBT_Autors.Post;
//FM_Data.IBTransaction1.Commit;
FM_Data.DS_Autors.Enabled := false;
DBGRid1.Enabled := false;

FM_Data.IBQ_Autors.Close;
FM_Data.IBQ_Autors.Active := false;
//FM_Data.IBQ_Autors.ExecSQL;
FM_Data.IBQ_Autors.Active := true;
FM_Data.IBQ_Autors.Open;
FM_Data.DS_Autors.Enabled := true;
DBGRid1.Enabled := true;
ShowMessage('YES');
```

Здесь IBQ_Autors - TIBQuery, IBT_Autors - TIBTable, DS_Autors - TDataSource, ну а дальше всё понятно. Наворотил, конечно, здорово. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне делать?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился очень просто. Надо просто, чтобы все компоненты, связанные с Базой Данных были на одной форме - на той же самой, где и таблица с кнопками и кодом обработки того, что связано с БД. Короче, если, допустим, TIBDataBase находится на другой форме, то ничего хорошего не выйдет.